# Code management for 2 solutions, same code, different refs and framework

Tags: c#, project

I have 2 versions for my application, their code must be exact, both refer to the same 3rd party SDK but in its different version and a different target framework.
The 3rd party DLLs are with the same name, only different path (i reference to relative common path).
I use git as source control, what I currently do is copy each file I change to the other folder - Manually.
If I change SomeClass.cs in version 2 -> then I manually copy it to version 1.

Is there a better way ?
What I do in large changes ?? -> copy the entire folder, with the .csproj and .cs -> If there is not better solution, maybe I will continue doing this - but only copy .cs files...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider having two branches - for each version. Then you would not have the code duplication and you would not have to copy the files. The drawback will be that you would have to merge the branches... I would prefer the solution with NuGet more but I know it involves more more work.

Comment: This could be good idea to make merge, and track only the .cs files, unstage all the .csproj..

Answer (score 0):

If the third party SDK is not already available as a public Nuget I would package it up in a private Nuget package and serve it using a private repo. [This page](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) talke about hosting your own Nuget repo if you are not already familiar with it. I'm not 100% sure from your description if you projects were using the same or different versions of the third party dlls, but in either case using Nuget would allow the projects to use the same or different revisions of the package as desired.